# Mysql multiple GROUP_CONCAT with distinct count per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a place_analytics table where I fetch followed places per month, my problem is that, when I fetch distinct count on monthly basis, it simply ignores the distinct value and fetched unwanted(described in screenshot) record based on monthly basis.

Note: A user can follow/unfollow same place multiple times, I do not delete this data but store with multiple entries.

For instance, in below screenshot, I have filtered the result based on place_id, where user_id=5 follows place_id=4 in May, unfollows it in July, then follows back also in July.

[image]

When I query,

```
SELECT place_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as follow_count 
FROM place_analytics 
WHERE is_followed=1
GROUP BY place_id
```

[image]

which is expected results, But, when I add another group by clause by months as,

```
MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(created_at), '%m'))
```

It returns, following result set where place_id 4 appears multiple times.

[image]

**QUESTION**
If user_id=5 has followed/unfollowed the place_id=4 in May, and followed in July. My query should only consider one record through out the table and ignore monthly group by. Is this possible?

Detail [MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35f91d/1) is here,

Expected result should be,

[image]

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: I have added result from sql fiddle, you can find the query and schema from fiddle link.